# UITableView does not scroll if I add a Tap Gesture Recogniser to the TableView

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to have a tap gesture recogniser with the UITableView. But if I add a gesture recogniser, scrolling function of UITableView doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Will you please give more description to have an exact thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];

[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];



-(void)tap
{

NSLog(@"You are Tap on Table.....");    

}
```

It's working try it.

Comment: If this helps anyone - Had the same problem. My mistake was using _setGestureRecognizers_ instead of _addGestureRecognizer_. I guess it was overwriting the original need recognizers for scrolling.